# Disable notifications from GitHub bots

Tags: github

Some of the GitHub repositories I'm watching use automated bots that make lots of trivial pull requests. Is there a way to disable all notifications from these bots (I think they are GitHub apps)? Alternatively, is there a way to disable all notifications from a specific app or user? This would accomplish the same goal. I would still like to keep watching the repositories as there are occasionally non-trivial commits by humans.

Answer (score 6):

> **Alternatively, is there a way to disable all notifications from a specific app or user?**

You can block a user, which would disable all notifications from that person (or bot).

To block someone, click the ***Block or report user*** on their profile page, then choose ***Block user***.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I can't find a similar block button for apps.

Comment: @Lassi Do the bots/apps have unique names?

Comment: I think so. Here's the main one: https://github.com/apps/renovate

Comment: This does not work with github-actions Bot.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I disabled notifications (in mobile view) from pullbot user made by pullbot service which is used to update my forks of repositories.

Comment: i don't understand this. Isn't this just muting the repo, not the bots?

Comment: I think it helped previously, probably some GitHub bots/apps are installed on repo and do not act as separate user accounts

Answer (score 1):

Afaik you can only remove bots from your own repositories, but you cannot silence or block a bot on someone else's repository.

We should maybe all report abuse for common bots, which maybe prompts github to add a feature to block others' bots.  Another option would be adding this feature to gitlab, and promoting that feature on twitter, etc.

If you receive notificaitons by email then your mail client could drop all notifications by Dependabot or others.  See https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/managing-subscriptions-and-notifications-on-github/setting-up-notifications/configuring-notifications

I'm unsure if there is a web interface suitable to script removal of notifications, but maybe so since github provides its own android app.